# JS Constant UK Timezone

Tags: javascript, time, clock

I'd like the timestamp on this div to always show UK time regardless of where you are in the world. Currently it will show based on the user/browser location even though i've added the below to ensure UK time is visible.

```
function showDateTime() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("time");
  var event = new Date();
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }));
```

When I try something different i.e the below, to test it's working, it doesn't change.

```
function showDateTime() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("time");
  var event = new Date();
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' }));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xgwsk2b3/

Comment: I _do_ see different things, `'05/01/2022, 14:21:36'` vs. `'1/5/2022, 9:21:36 AM'`

Comment: Yep, I do see a difference as well.

Comment: Me too = en-gb: `05/01/2022, 14:22:36` vs en-US: `1/5/2022, 2:22:36 PM`

Comment: toLocaleString won't change the displayed time - only the format of it.

Comment: Thanks all, maybe I just needed to ask someone outside the UK to look :D